# Move view which is not fit to finger

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project in which user can move view with finger touch . It works but not accurate to the finger position. I am not asking the good code you have, but rather to wondering why my code make the view not fit to the finger. It's like the view have more margin about 20dp.Here's the code :

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lyRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.zihadrizkyef.dragviewwithfinger.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.zihadrizkyef.dragviewwithfinger;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    ViewGroup lyRoot;
    TextView tvText;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lyRoot = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.lyRoot);
        tvText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)tvText.getLayoutParams();

        lyRoot.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getRawX();
        int y = (int)event.getRawY();
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            layoutParams.leftMargin = x;
            layoutParams.topMargin = y;
            tvText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
        lyRoot.invalidate();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            System.out.println("mouseX:"+x+" ; mouseY:"+y);
            System.out.println("viewX:"+layoutParams.leftMargin+" ; viewY:"+layoutParams.topMargin);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the dragged distance instead of the coordinates on screen.

```
layoutParams.leftMargin = layoutParams.leftMargin + deltaX;
layoutParams.topMargin = layoutParams.leftMargin + deltaY;
```

You can get the full solution from Android developers site
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html#drag

You will have to adapt it to your needs. I adapted it a little.

```
// The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);
            final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, pointerIndex);
            final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, pointerIndex);

            // Remember where we started (for dragging)
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            // Save the ID of this pointer (for dragging)
            mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, 0);
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
            final int pointerIndex =
                    MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(ev, mActivePointerId);

            final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, pointerIndex);
            final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, pointerIndex);

            // Calculate the distance moved
            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

            layoutParams.leftMargin += dx;
            layoutParams.topMargin += dy;
            tvText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            lyRoot.invalidate();

            // Remember this touch position for the next move event
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);
            final int pointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, pointerIndex);

            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the link. But It doesn't mean that using screen coordinate is wrong, doesn't it? I just prefer to use screen coordinate. So can you please tell my code's mistake?

Comment: No, the example I showed you also use the screen coordinates but they are then adjusted. I mean you will always have that extra margin (20dp or more) because `event.getRawX()` is the position on screen where you tap. You need instead the dragged distance to set precise *leftMargin*

Comment: Try to adapt for your needs the code I posted. It works for sure because I used it in one of my projects. Otherwise you will always have that random margin.